# Can a non-root modify environment variables?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Can a non-root (without sudo permissions) run the following command:

```
export PATH=/tml:$PATH
```

If so, how does it work?

I thought *environment variables* are read-only for non-root users, while *shell variables* can be modified freely.

Comment: "I thought environment variables are read-only," Why did you think that?

Comment: @muru for non-root users

Comment: The question remains. What did you read or see that makes you think so?

Comment: To my understanding, environment variables (unlike shell variables) are global. Which means they apply to every process. This is very dangerous if any user can modify values there.

Comment: Every process has a *copy* of environment variables inherited from its parent, and can modify its own set of environment variables and also the set of environment variables passed to child processes upon creation.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I tried to solve a ctf challenge where there was a weak user with a sudo permission to run "date --date 'yesterday'" as root. The solution was to create an executable named 'date' and change the PATH env variable so it will reach the modified 'date' executable. 
I'm still not sure how it works because root's PATH variable shouldn't be affected.

Comment: That still shouldn't have worked as stated. For sudo, if permission is given for a specific command, the full path to that command has to be specified. If it worked for you, the sudo configuration was some very insecure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the following commands should convince you that you can modify your environment variables.

```
$ grep PATH ~/.profile 
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
    PATH=~/bin:"${PATH}"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/games"

$ ls -l ~/.profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 sudodus sudodus 632 dec 10  2010 /home/sudodus/.profile
```

In other words, you can not only modify these variables temporarily, but also make it persist by modifying your configuration file `~/.profile`. You, as a regular user can do it.

---

The following command line shows system files, where the PATH is set or modified

```
sudo grep -r 'PATH=' /etc/*
```

You may want to get more details. See for example the following link,

[Unix & Linux: Complete view of where the PATH variable is set in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227989/complete-view-of-where-the-path-variable-is-set-in-bash) - particularly the answer by Gilles.

Comment: So any user can change environment variables GLOBALY? And it will apply on root as well? Seems like I'm missing something here.

Comment: You can change ***your*** environment variables, but not for other users unless you have superuser permisisons (can use `sudo`).